# Use ForEach extension in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using an IEnumerable extension to loop through a collection and also get its index:

```
@Model.ForEach((card, i) => {
  @<li class="c@(i)">@card.Text</li>;
})
```

The ForEach extension is the following:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T, Int32> action) {

  Int32 i = 0;
  foreach (T item in source) {
    action(item, i);
    i++;
  }

} // ForEach
```

But when I try to compile it I get the following error message:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to
>   'System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult'

How can I solve this? Do I need a new extension?

Comment: Interesting problem - easily resolved by just using `@for(...)` in the view instead of the extension method of course.

Comment: Another issue is that the body of your foreach clause does not translate to an Action delegate.  You're trying to imply a razor transition from code to html that it doesn't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that Razor expects your `ForEach` method to return a value, such as `MvcHtmlString`.

Also, you cannot simply expect Razor to translate the body of your foreach clause to work with your Action delegate.  There is a way to get this to work, but it's not as pretty.  I'd suggest using the `@for(...)` clause as James suggested if you want to use the standard razor syntax.

However, here's an implementation that does work:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Int32, string> selector)
{
    return new MvcHtmlString(String.Join("\n", source.Select(selector)));
}
```

Usage:

```
@Model.ForEach((card, i) =>
{
    return "<li class=c" + i + ">" + card.Text + "</li>";
})
```

Comment: Conceptually this is representing `Aggregate`, not `ForEach`, as you're transforming each item in the sequence into something else, and then combining all of those things into a result.  You could actually implement it with operations that make that clearer, not that yours is wrong, by doing something more like, `return new MvcHtmlString(string.Join("\n", source.Select(action)));`.  Additionally, `action` isn't actually an action anymore, since it generates a value.  It's a `selector` now; I'd suggest renaming that.

Comment: @Servy Ya, that does condense it quite a bit. I'll update that.  I'll leave the name of the method up to the op though and leave as is.

Answer (score 2):

This works, but it feels hackish:

```
public static HelperResult ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, int, Func<TextWriter, HelperResult>> action) {
  return new HelperResult((writer) => {
    int i = 0;
    foreach (T item in source) {
      action(item, i)(writer).WriteTo(writer);
      i++;
    }
  });
}

@Model.ForEach((card, i) => 
    @<li class="c@(i)">@card.Text</li>
)
```