# C# mvc use List where condition even if there are Object reference not set to an instance of an object errir

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, razor, nullreferenceexception

I have searched this website for answers for my question, but didnt find :(

My question is:

I have code (in this case I use razor code):

```
@foreach (IAccountingOfferAmount accountingAmount in Model.AccountingOfferAmountList)
{
  if(offerProduct.OfferProductId == accountingAmount.OfferProductId)
  {
    <span>@accountingAmount.BookAmount</span>
  }
}
```

[above code is working version and have no problems with that)

which is equivalent to

```
@Model.AccountingOfferAmountList
   .Where(x => x.OfferProductId == offerProduct.OfferProductId)
   .FirstOrDefault().BookAmount.ToString();
```

The problem is:

if (x => x.OfferProductId == offerProduct.OfferProductId) returns null , the code will not able to select "BookAmount" value and will throw "Object reference not set to an instance of an object error."

I can write:

```
var test =  Model.AccountingOfferAmountList
      .Where(x => x.OfferProductId == offerProduct.OfferProductId)
      .FirstOrDefault();

if(test != null)
{
  <span>@test.BookAmount.ToString()</span>
}
```

and this will work..

but my question is:

Is there any option do not use "foreach" and "if" clauses (even without any variables) and just use one line of code ,
so it will ignore null results?

for example:

```
@Model.AccountingOfferAmountList.Where(x => x.OfferProductId == offerProduct.OfferProductId)
    .DefaultIfNull(String.Empty)
    .FirstOrDefault().BookAmount.ToString();
```

(not working example of course, just an idea if in case gets null, there will print "" and will not continue to .FirstOrDefault().BookAmount.ToString())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom HTML helper like this:

[Use ForEach extension in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498283/use-foreach-extension-in-razor)

> ```
> public static MvcHtmlString ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Int32, string> selector)
> {
>     return new MvcHtmlString(String.Join("\n", source.Select(selector)));
> }
> ```

And you can write like this in cshtml:

```
@Model.AccountingOfferAmountList.Where(x => x.OfferProductId == offerProduct.OfferProductId).ForEach((x,i) => $"<span>{x.BookAmount}</span>")
```